# $1+yx$ is left-invertible if and only if $1+yx$ is invertible

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring (with multiplicative identity $1$) and fix $x\in R$. I want to show that

> $1+yx$ is left-invertible for all $y\in R$ if and only if $1+yx$ is
>   invertible for all $y\in R$.

We say that $r\in R$ is *left-invertible* if there exists $s\in R$ such that $sr=1$. Moreover, we say that $r\in R$ is *invertible* if there exists $s\in R$ such that $sr=1=rs$.

From the definition, one of the directions is trivial. Namely, if $1+yx$ is invertible for all $y\in R$, then $1+yx$ is left-invertible for all $y\in R$. However, I am having trouble with the converse.

Comment: This is a great exercise. Note that the title of your post is not the same as what you need to prove! The fact that it's true for _all_ $y$ is crucial!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $1+yx$ is left-invertible for all $y\in R$. Then $$s(1+yx)=1$$ for some $s\in R$. We can rewrite the equation above as 
$$s = 1- syx.$$
Since $-sy\in R$, $s$ is left-invertible, and thus $$rs=1$$ for some $r\in R$. Putting everything together,
$$r = rs(1+yx) = 1+yx.$$
Hence, $1+yx$ is invertible.